# About $ p $-fitting subgroup of finite group $ G $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$ Fit_{p}(G) $ is the maximum normal $ p $-nilpotent subgroup of $ G $ that $ p $ is a prime. How to show $ Fit_{p}(G) $ equals the intersection of the centralizers of the chief factors of $ G $ whose orders are divisible by $ p $ ? By the previous post, if $ N $ the minimal normal subgroup of $ G $ whose divisible by $ p $ and $ K $ is a normal $ p $-nilpotent subgroup of $ G $, then $ [ N , K]=1 $.